# ioctl error on drawing to a framebuffer in vulkan

Tags: android, android-ndk, vulkan

I am writing a game for **Android devices** which uses the **Android NDK** and **Vulkan** if it is supported (and OpenGL otherwise).  I am currently working on doing shadows in Vulkan.  This requires **drawing in a framebuffer** and using the results in the shader that is used to draw to the screen.  I noticed that when I use a framebuffer with images the same size as the swapchain images, I get a lot of slow down and an error from the backend driver saying: "ioctl... failed: errno 35 Resource deadlock would occur".  Eventually I get a device lost error (VK_ERROR_DEVICE_LOST).  If I use a framebuffer with images that are half the width and half the height of the swapchain images, then everything works fine.  In all cases, I get no error from the Vulkan validation layers.

I also get graphics corruption in *other* applications after I get the device lost error in my game.  This is bad news, I think.  I should not be able to affect other running programs.

The full text of the error is:

```
W/Adreno-GSL: <gsl_ldd_control:549>: ioctl fd 54 code 0x400c0907 (IOCTL_KGSL_DEVICE_WAITTIMESTAMP_CTXTID) failed: errno 35 Resource deadlock would occur
```

Does anyone know why this would be happening?  Am I doing something wrong?  And if it is a driver error, any ideas on how to detect it without causing graphics corruption in my game or other programs?

device details:

```
name: Pixel 4XL phone
Vulkan API version: 1.1.87
Vulkan device name: Adreno (TM) 640
NDK version:  I tried 20.1.5948944 and 21.0.6113669. They both have the problem.
Android version: 10
VkPhysicalDeviceProperties.limits.maxImageDimension2D = 16384
VkPhysicalDeviceProperties.limits.maxFramebufferWidth = 16384
VkPhysicalDeviceProperties.limits.maxFramebufferHeight = 16384
VkSurfaceCapabilitiesKHR.currentExtent.width = 1440
VkSurfaceCapabilitiesKHR.currentExtent.height = 2690
Width of the images in the framebuffer when the problem occurred: 1440
Height of the images in the framebuffer when the problem occurred: 2690
```

The pipeline is created with:

```
VkViewport viewport = {};
viewport.x = 0.0f;
viewport.y = 0.0f;
viewport.width = (float) VkSurfaceCapabilitiesKHR.currentExtent.width;
viewport.height = (float) VkSurfaceCapabilitiesKHR.currentExtent.height;
```

The framebuffer is created with:

```
VkFramebufferCreateInfo framebufferInfo = {};
framebufferInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_FRAMEBUFFER_CREATE_INFO;
framebufferInfo.renderPass = inRenderPass->renderPass().get();
framebufferInfo.attachmentCount = static_cast<uint32_t>(inAttachments.size());
framebufferInfo.pAttachments = inAttachments.data();
framebufferInfo.width = VkSurfaceCapabilitiesKHR.currentExtent.width;
framebufferInfo.height = VkSurfaceCapabilitiesKHR.currentExtent.height;
framebufferInfo.layers = 1;
```

The images are created with:

```
VkImageCreateInfo imageInfo = {};
imageInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_IMAGE_CREATE_INFO;
imageInfo.imageType = VK_IMAGE_TYPE_2D;
imageInfo.extent.width = VkSurfaceCapabilitiesKHR.currentExtent.width;
imageInfo.extent.height = VkSurfaceCapabilitiesKHR.currentExtent.height;
```

Please let me know if you need any more info from these structures or other code.  It is all very long :-)

Output from the android device when the problem occurs:

```
04/23 21:09:22: Launching 'app' on Google Pixel 4 XL.
$ adb shell am start -n "com.quasar.cerulean.amazinglabyrinth/com.quasar.cerulean.amazinglabyrinth.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Waiting for process to come online...
Connected to process 7507 on device 'google-pixel_4_xl-**************'.
Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
W/mazinglabyrint: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (greylist, reflection, allowed)
W/mazinglabyrint: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
I/Adreno: QUALCOMM build                   : 9b214d0, Ibc75db1fca
    Build Date                       : 06/30/19
    OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: EV031.26.06.00
    Local Branch                     : AU124
    Remote Branch                    :
    Remote Branch                    :
    Reconstruct Branch               :
    Build Config                     : S P 8.0.6 AArch64
I/Adreno: PFP: 0x016ee185, ME: 0x00000000
D/vulkan: searching for layers in '/data/app/com.quasar.cerulean.amazinglabyrinth-************************/lib/arm64'
D/vulkan: added global layer 'VK_LAYER_LUNARG_parameter_validation' from library '/data/app/com.quasar.cerulean.amazinglabyrinth-************************/lib/arm64/libVkLayer_parameter_validation.so'
D/vulkan: added global layer 'VK_LAYER_KHRONOS_validation' from library '/data/app/com.quasar.cerulean.amazinglabyrinth-************************/lib/arm64/libVkLayer_khronos_validation.so'
D/vulkan: added global layer 'VK_LAYER_GOOGLE_unique_objects' from library '/data/app/com.quasar.cerulean.amazinglabyrinth-************************/lib/arm64/libVkLayer_unique_objects.so'
D/vulkan: added global layer 'VK_LAYER_GOOGLE_threading' from library '/data/app/com.quasar.cerulean.amazinglabyrinth-************************/lib/arm64/libVkLayer_threading.so'
D/vulkan: added global layer 'VK_LAYER_LUNARG_object_tracker' from library '/data/app/com.quasar.cerulean.amazinglabyrinth-************************/lib/arm64/libVkLayer_object_tracker.so'
D/vulkan: added global layer 'VK_LAYER_LUNARG_core_validation' from library '/data/app/com.quasar.cerulean.amazinglabyrinth-************************/lib/arm64/libVkLayer_core_validation.so'
D/vulkan: searching for layers in '/data/app/com.quasar.cerulean.amazinglabyrinth-************************/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a'
I/vulkan: Loaded layer VK_LAYER_KHRONOS_validation
I/Adreno: QUALCOMM build          : 9b214d0, Ibc75db1fca
    Build Date              : 06/30/19
    Shader Compiler Version : EV031.26.06.00
    Local Branch            : AU124
    Remote Branch           :
    Remote Branch           :
    Reconstruct Branch      :
    Build Config            : S P 8.0.6 AArch64
E/Looper: Invalid attempt to set NULL callback but not allowed for this looper.
W/Adreno-GSL: <gsl_ldd_control:549>: ioctl fd 54 code 0x400c0907 (IOCTL_KGSL_DEVICE_WAITTIMESTAMP_CTXTID) failed: errno 35 Resource deadlock would occur
    <log_gpu_snapshot:458>: panel.gpuSnapshotPath is not set.not generating user snapshot
```

The following function is being used to allocate all images:

```
void Image::createImage(VkFormat format, VkImageTiling tiling,
                        VkImageUsageFlags usage,
                        VkMemoryPropertyFlags properties) {

    VkImageCreateInfo imageInfo = {};
    imageInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_IMAGE_CREATE_INFO;
    imageInfo.imageType = VK_IMAGE_TYPE_2D;
    imageInfo.extent.width = m_width;
    imageInfo.extent.height = m_height;
    imageInfo.extent.depth = 1;
    imageInfo.mipLevels = 1;
    imageInfo.arrayLayers = 1;

    imageInfo.format = format;
    imageInfo.tiling = tiling;

    imageInfo.initialLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_UNDEFINED;
    imageInfo.usage = usage;
    imageInfo.sharingMode = VK_SHARING_MODE_EXCLUSIVE;
    imageInfo.samples = VK_SAMPLE_COUNT_1_BIT;

    VkImage imageRaw;
    if (vkCreateImage(m_device->logicalDevice().get(), &imageInfo, nullptr, &imageRaw) != VK_SUCCESS) {
        throw std::runtime_error("failed to create image!");
    }

    auto const &capDevice = m_device;
    auto imageDeleter = [capDevice](VkImage imageRaw) {
        vkDestroyImage(capDevice->logicalDevice().get(), imageRaw, nullptr);
    };

    m_image.reset(imageRaw, imageDeleter);

    VkMemoryRequirements memRequirements;
    vkGetImageMemoryRequirements(m_device->logicalDevice().get(), m_image.get(), &memRequirements);

    VkMemoryAllocateInfo allocInfo = {};
    allocInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_MEMORY_ALLOCATE_INFO;
    allocInfo.allocationSize = memRequirements.size;
    allocInfo.memoryTypeIndex = m_device->findMemoryType(memRequirements.memoryTypeBits, properties);

    VkDeviceMemory imageMemoryRaw;
    if (vkAllocateMemory(m_device->logicalDevice().get(), &allocInfo, nullptr, &imageMemoryRaw) !=
        VK_SUCCESS) {
        throw std::runtime_error("failed to allocate image memory!");
    }

    auto memoryDeleter = [capDevice](VkDeviceMemory imageMemoryRaw) {
        vkFreeMemory(capDevice->logicalDevice().get(), imageMemoryRaw, nullptr);
    };

    m_imageMemory.reset(imageMemoryRaw, memoryDeleter);

    vkBindImageMemory(m_device->logicalDevice().get(), m_image.get(), m_imageMemory.get(), 0);
}
```

The color attachment is created with:

```
createImage(
   VK_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_SFLOAT,
   VK_IMAGE_TILING_OPTIMAL,
   VK_IMAGE_USAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_BIT | VK_IMAGE_USAGE_SAMPLED_BIT,
   VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_DEVICE_LOCAL_BIT)

m_width = m_swapChain->extent().width;
m_height = m_swapChain->extent().height;
```

The depth attachment is created with:

```
createImage(
   VK_FORMAT_D32_SFLOAT,
   VK_IMAGE_TILING_OPTIMAL,
   VK_IMAGE_USAGE_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT_BIT,
   VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_DEVICE_LOCAL_BIT)

m_width = m_swapChain->extent().width;
m_height = m_swapChain->extent().height;
```

Comment: Probably not quite enough information here to go on. The format of the image might help and how you are allocating memory for it.

Comment: I added the image creation code to the question.

Comment: I tried to create images of a similar size on a similar device (same GPU) and didn't get an error, so it doesn't seem like that is directly the issue. Unfortunately the validation layers don't pick up every problem so there could still be a problem elsewhere. The error message isn't too helpful though. You could try the Khronos Slack channels for help: https://khr.io/slack - a fair few driver developers can be found there as well as other Android devs.

Comment: Thanks so much for the reference to Khronos Slack channels, I will try that.  Note: I was able to create the images fine and even draw to them for about 400 times before the problem occurred.